# Thank you for giving me the floor-VS-Thank you to give me the floor

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

**Thank you for giving me the floor.**
           vs 
**Thank you to give me the floor.**

Are they both correct?  If yes, Are they have same meaning?

Answer (score 2):

*Thank you for x-ing ...* is idiomatic.

*Thank you to x ...* is not.

But *I'll thank you to x ...* is grammatical, and is an idiom meaning something like "I demand that you do this, but I'm pretending that I'm being polite".

As far as I know, there is no explanation for this: it's just the way English works.

Comment: If I compare 1) *I don't like my dog **sleeping** in an outdoor kennel* and 2) *I don't like my dog **to sleep** in an outdoor kennel*, it seems to me #1 is far more likely if we're in a context where the dog *does in fact* sleep outdoors (***but*** speaker doesn't like this arrangement), whereas #2 is more likely if it *doesn't* (***because*** that's not what the speaker wants to happen). Or am I just imagining this distinction?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree with your distinction, but I wouldn't put the difference as strongly as you do.

Comment: Well, it may not be the best possible example for illustrating the distinction. And I freely admit I overstated things with *is **far** more likely*. How about ***Watching / To watch** the 9 o'clock news is boring. Let's go down the pub instead.* It occurs to me that the main reason the "infinitive" version there sounds a bit "off" is because I'd expect ***would be boring*** (if we *were* to watch the news), where ***is boring*** quite naturally invites us to assume the conversants are ***currently*** watching the news.